# Why does firewalld deny nft masquerade traffic from my LAN?

Tags: nftables

I'm trying to share wifi internet over an ethernet LAN. Two machines A and B, both running Fedora 32, are joined by an ethernet switch, and A is connected to the internet over wifi. In `firewalld.conf`:

```
FirewallBackend=nftables
```

Using `nft` I added a nat table and a masquerade rule:

```
# nft list table nat -a
table ip nat { # handle 7
    chain postrouting { # handle 2
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 10.0.0.0/24 counter packets 18 bytes 1255 masquerade # handle 13
    }
}
```

Machine B has IP `10.0.0.4` and has access everywhere within the LAN, and it can ping `8.8.8.8`, but it cannot `telnet 8.8.8.8 80` (no route to host). Same result on B for basically any other internet request.

```
# journalctl -x -e
...
FINAL_REJECT: IN=wan0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=10.188.xx.xxx DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=328 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=28534 PROTO=UDP SPT=68 DPT=67 LEN=308
...
```

It looks like the request from B is going out, but the response is getting blocked at the firewall coming back in on `wan0` for some reason.

How can I debug `firewalld` to find out what rule it is applying there? I really don't see why the log statement gives no reference to the basis of the decision to reject the traffic. Is there a way to see more about the logic happening inside the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to share my internet connection goes like this:

1. `dnf install firewall-config`
2. open the app from a root shell (otherwise it constantly nags for a password)
3. move the `lan0` interface into the `trusted` zone
4. enable address translation on the default `FedoraWorkstation` zone
5. execute the changes permanently (options menu)
6. restart the firewall (options menu)

The correct modifications appear in `nft list ruleset`. So I still don't really know how it works. But it does work, and the app is intuitive and complete enough that I don't really need the CLI.